# excel macros simply disappeared

Tags: vba

I was working the whole day with my excel file, that contains a few macros, then, all of sudden, the macros are not there. I have tried everything, but I neither can see the codes, nor create new macros. I did went check to see if there was a disabled add-in, but there isn't. What can I do to solve this issue??

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? What are your security settings? Are you using a **.xlsm** filetype ?

Comment: hello, it is version 2104, year 2021 and, yes, .xlsm file type. Any idea of what is going on??